# Generating all third-party Django apps endpoints with drf-yasg

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth, drf-yasg

Is there a way for generating all third-party apps endpoints with drf-yasg?

So I have installed social_django app and want to include all URLs it provides to swagger UI

My urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('', include('user.urls')),
    re_path(r'^$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    re_path(r'', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    re_path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Schema

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Snippets API",
        default_version='v1',
        description="Test description",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)
```

Those are that defined by me, but I also want to see here /login/facebook/ , /login/google-oauth2/ etc. Or for example simple /admin/ that Django provides.

How can I do this?
[image: swagger endpoints]